# npm package has dependency errors, even after I manually install them

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I'm trying to use this [Imgur package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imgur) from NPM in my Angular web application. After installing it, everything seemed fine. Even after importing it. However, once Initialized a variable using the package, I get compile errors that claim there are resolve errors in my code, such as 'crypto'.
NPM version: 5.6.0
Angular version: 6.2.9

Any idea as to what may have caused this issue? Any idea on how to fix it?

I tried installing the seemingly missing packages, but they were still seen as missing when I tried to compile again.
I also tried downgrading my node version to older versions, to no avail.
Neither did deleting my node_modules and reinstalling them.

Here is the code I use to initialize the module in typescript:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Convert from 'color-convert';
import * as Hex from 'hex2dec';
import * as ClarifaiSVC from '../clarifai_service/clarifai.service';
import * as Imgur from 'imgur';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-imagery',
    templateUrl: './imagery.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./imagery.component.css']
})

export class ImageryComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private Clarifai: ClarifaiSVC.ClarifaiService, private Imgur: Imgur) { }
}
```

This is what it says in the npm log after serving:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/aws-sign2/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\Gilian\Documents\School\3EA2_18-19\Internet Of Things\src\dashboard\dashboard\node_modules\aws-sign2'ERROR in ./node_modules/aws4/aws4.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\Gilian\Documents\School\3EA2_18-19\Internet Of Things\src\dashboard\dashboard\node_modules\aws4'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ecc-jsbn/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\Gilian\Documents\School\3EA2_18-19\Internet Of Things\src\dashboard\dashboard\node_modules\ecc-jsbn'
ERROR in ./node_modules/http-signature/lib/verify.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\Gilian\Documents\School\3EA2_18-19\Internet Of Things\src\dashboard\dashboard\node_modules\http-signature\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/http-signature/lib/signer.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\Gilian\Documents\School\3EA2_18-19\Internet Of Things\src\dashboard\dashboard\node_modules\http-signature\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/oauth-sign/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\Gilian\Documents\School\3EA2_18-19\Internet Of Things\src\dashboard\dashboard\node_modules\oauth-sign'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/oauth.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\Gilian\Documents\School\3EA2_18-19\Internet Of Things\src\dashboard\dashboard\node_modules\request\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/helpers.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\Gilian\Documents\School\3EA2_18-19\Internet Of Things\src\dashboard\dashboard\node_modules\request\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/hawk.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\Gilian\Documents\School\3EA2_18-19\Internet Of Things\src\dashboard\dashboard\node_modules\request\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/identity.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\Gilian\Documents\School\3EA2_18-19\Internet Of Things\src\dashboard\dashboard\node_modules\sshpk\lib'ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/utils.js
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/openssh-cert.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\Gilian\Documents\School\3EA2_18-19\Internet Of Things\src\dashboard\dashboard\node_modules\sshpk\lib\formats'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/ssh-private.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\Gilian\Documents\School\3EA2_18-19\Internet Of Things\src\dashboard\dashboard\node_modules\sshpk\lib\formats'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs.realpath/old.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\Gilian\Documents\School\3EA2_18-19\Internet Of Things\src\dashboard\dashboard\node_modules\fs.realpath'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\Gilian\Documents\School\3EA2_18-19\Internet Of Things\src\dashboard\dashboard\node_modules\request\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\Gilian\Documents\School\3EA2_18-19\Internet Of Things\src\dashboard\dashboard\node_modules\tunnel-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Users\Gilian\Documents\School\3EA2_18-19\Internet Of Things\src\dashboard\dashboard\node_modules\forever-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Users\Gilian\Documents\School\3EA2_18-19\Internet Of Things\src\dashboard\dashboard\node_modules\request'
--------------------------------------------


--------------------------------------------
This just goes on for a while
--------------------------------------------


--------------------------------------------
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\Gilian\Documents\School\3EA2_18-19\Internet Of Things\src\dashboard\dashboard\node_modules\request'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/ed-compat.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\Gilian\Documents\School\3EA2_18-19\Internet Of Things\src\dashboard\dashboard\node_modules\sshpk\lib'ERROR in ./node_modules/request/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\Users\Gilian\Documents\School\3EA2_18-19\Internet Of Things\src\dashboard\dashboard
```

Comment: can you try deleting your node_modules and try running `npm install` again.

Comment: @Abhishek I just tried, still the same

Comment: I edited the question accordingly

Comment: Which version of Node.js are you using?

Comment: @laptou I'm on node version 8.11.2

Comment: Most of the modules that it is complaining cannot be found are modules that are built into Node.js (`crypto`, `fs`, `http`, etc) so I do not think that this is a problem with your `node_modules`. I think there is some sort of problem with your Node installation.

Comment: You mentioned that you are trying to combine this stuff with Angular, which means that you are running your code in a web browser? How are you doing that? Are you using a bundler, like [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org), [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org), or [Parcel](https://parceljs.org)?

Comment: @laptou — A bundler isn't going to make Node built-its work in the browser.

Comment: @I'm not sure (I'm not the one who set up the project/environment) but I have seen webpack be used when going through the logs.

Comment: @Quentin You are partially right; some modules (like `crypto`) can be shimmed using in-browser equivalents, while others (like `fs`) will just break.

Comment: @laptou — The module also depends on `fs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Crypto is a built-in Node.js module](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html). It is not vanilla JavaScript.

The `imgur` module is not designed to run in a web browser, so it won't work with Angular. It has dependencies on a lot of Node.js-specific APIs (such as file writing).

Comment: That's seems odd, since it specifically gives examples to write javascript applications with the module.

Comment: @MyNameIsGuzse — Why is it odd that a module for Node.js would use JavaScript? The whole point of Node.js is that it runs programs written in JavaScript.

Comment: I guess I've barely seen javascript be used outside of web development. This does mean i have a problem though, because i have no idea how to connect to the imgur API trough typescript alone...

Comment: I googled imgur api and [this](https://apidocs.imgur.com/) was the first hit. There is a link to *Example HTML5/JavaScript app* in there.

Answer (score 0):

Your installation seems broken. Best way is to manually delete the `node_modules` folder and run npm install all over again. This should work post the fresh installation.

Comment: I just did, but I still get the same error. I should have added this to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `node_modules` and run `npm install` again...

Besides **imgur**, you have to install its types too.

`npm install @types/imgur`

Comment: And don't forget to run `npm cache clean -f` after removing `node_modules` directory.

Comment: I just tried, reinstalling node_modules didn't help.
When trying to install @types/imgur, i get `404 Not Found: @types/imgur@latest`

Comment: @kav After cleaning the cache, I can't reinstall the node_modules at all. now i get an error that says `npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>`